# Create folder and file with contents from multiple rows of cell data in excel

Tags: excel, vba

I would like to create a text file with contents and save it in a folder, all of which generated from cell data in Excel.
I have the folder and file name that I would like to be created from data in column A1:A2180
I have the contents which I would like to be saved as a .doc or .txt file in column B1:B2180,C1:C2180
So each row will be saved as a text file with the contents from columns B and C in an individual folder created by the script.
Is this possible,
Thank you so much in advance.

Comment: Yes it's possible but here we like you to try first.  If you're having problems implementing this then describe exactly which part has got you stumped, including any code you may have, even if it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
Sub Macro2()

Dim fso As Object
Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Dim oFile As Object

rowMax = Cells(1, 1).End(xlDown).Row

For i = 1 To rowMax

    Set oFile = fso.CreateTextFile(Cells(i, 1))
    'Write column B
    oFile.WriteLine Cells(i, 2)
    'Write column C
    oFile.WriteLine Cells(i, 3)
    oFile.Close

    Set fso = Nothing
    Set oFile = Nothing

Next i

End Sub
```